# Can't access root folder on android emulator with cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying crawl the sdcard of the phone using cordova 3.4. Currently I'am trying this on an android emulator. 
I am able to acces the sdcard but the root folder is my application folder. 
How can I access the root folder of the sdcard (/storage/sdcard) ?

Here is the code I'am using :

```
function getFileSystem(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(window.requestFileSystem){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSystem){ 
                root = fileSystem.root;
                console.log("Root file system : "+root.fullPath); // here I'm getting '/'
                listFiles(root).then(function(files){
                    deferred.resolve(files);
                }, function(error){
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
            }, function(evt){ // error get file system
                console.log("File System Error: "+evt.target.error.code);
            }
        );
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I have tried root.getParent() but it return undefined
Any idea ?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible

Comment: The root of the SD card is certainly possible. The root of the device -- no. What version Cordova and Android? What version of the File plugin do you have installed?

Comment: cordova : 3.4.0-0.1.3

Comment: cordova : 3.4.0-0.1.3, for android I'am not sure, in the manifest file it's targetVersion="19". The file plugin was installed with command line so i don't the version.